# How to version and configure WebApi with multiple aliases

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, versioning

Currently I am do not have any informationabout my WebApi version in url. So all my endpoings looking like this http://mywebapi/api/getsomethig/id

I wan to have verson number in WebApi url as well but also want to keep the current alias. Is there a way I can configure my WebApi like that so it can respond with different aliaes:

- http://mywebapi/api/getsomethig/id
- http://mywebapi/api/v2.0/getsomethig/id
- http://mywebapi/api/v2/getsomethig/id

What is the best approach of doing that?