# ASP.NET WebAPI URL Versioning

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We want to create general public web services and we create customized APIs.
But how to isolate, version and bind those endpoints as a hyperscaled system?

We want to have:

- `https://api.domain.tld/v1/..`
- `https://api.domain.tld/v2/..`
- `https://api.domain.tld/latest/..`
- `https://api.domain.tld/bosch/v1/..`

or

- `https://domain.tld/api/v1/..`
- `https://domain.tld/api/v2/..`

All endpoints should be isolated. Behind an endpoint like `https://domain.tld/api/v2/..` exists at least 3 instances of an ASP.NET WebAPI. We do not want to separate versioning by namespaces inside the WebAPI project and use internal route configurations to resolve this.

We want to have this behavior onpremise and aswell on Azure.
Is there any recommendation or best practise and configuration samples out there?

I could only found one thread here ([How to version and configure WebApi with multiple aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214673/how-to-version-and-configure-webapi-with-multiple-aliases)) which is very old and there is no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the version as the api route, like you so:

```
https://domain.tld/api/v1/..
https://domain.tld/api/v2/..
```

which has always worked fine, but other use url parameters, which I find to be less explicit:

[Visual Studio Team Services - API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/builds)

I would just not recomend you to go with this pattern:

```
https://api.domain.tld/latest/..
https://api.domain.tld/bosch/v1/..
```

It would you make you API look a bit messy, but it could make sense if you use logical services in your API:

```
https://api.domain.tld/service1/v1
https://api.domain.tld/service1/v2
https://api.domain.tld/service2/v1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the question how to map the subfolders to separate instances is still open.  For example `https://api.domain.tld/service1/v1` is Instance3 on Server1 and `https://api.domain.tld/service1/v2` should be Instance9 on Server17. Is the load balancer responsible for this?

Comment: And the logical separation for customized APIs will be `https://api.domain.tld/bosch/userservice/v1` `https://api.domain.tld/bosch/orderservice/v3` but that leaves me here with the same problem: how to map sub directories to services.

Comment: Why do you need a load balance for that? That's just web api mappings we are talking about.

Comment: these are heavily used endpoints. We need to load balance them. Nobody here talks about the api mapping itself. My question is still: how to map virtual directories to bindings?! Behind `https://api.domain.tld/bosch/orderservice/v1` there can exists 7 instances. But how to map them?! In IIS I can only bind the domain `api.domain.tld` but not the additional `/bosch/orderservice/v1`. But we do not want to hold the API versioning inside the API Code and cover that with Routes. That is useless and not scalable!

Comment: Well, you can definitelly create multiple virtual directories but that would be a bit messy, having virtual directories to act as the version part of your URL. As for the load balance, I'm sorry but it seems that we're talking different things, the load balance works by dispatching requests to a single port, you don't have to worry about getting too many requests to the same port, and you surelly don't need diferent virtual sites fot that.

Comment: At this point we have different opinions. You configure endpoints for URLs to WebApp Ressources and at this point I cant see any solution to match the "recommended" api routes with an independend and isolated instance infrastructure. Every microservice should be isolated but how to isolate microservices if I cant sperate them by URLs? That is a bit pity.

Comment: If you want to bring miicroservices into the table then you need to update your question so I can give you a proper input, that said, there seems to be a big confusion over there. Microservices should be hidden from the outside, by using some sort of web gateway, you should'n really have a public API on top of each services, they are miicroservices for a reason. They do need to work in isolation but that doesn't mean they should have their own Web Interfaces. I know my comment won't really help you, but without knowing a bit more it is complicated to do any recomendations.

Comment: I think your point here is wrong and also the Microsoft recommendation differs from your point of view.

Comment: I don't know which point you're referring too and just saying that I am wrong because supposedly Microsoft does it differently does not make you right. In really it just shows the opposite, that you clearly have no idea about what you're talking about :)

Comment: But after re-reading my previous comment, I understand where you're coming from. All I said is that clients should not call the services directly, you can expose their functionality but not directly, you usually have same kind of web tier, web farms and such which load balance the requests to the proper services but it is this gateway that should be responsible for managing what sort of services your company is exposing which might just group a few microservices as well as other aspects such as authorization and authentication.

Comment: I dont care if Companies recommend another approach then generally recommended. But this all does not help me to map this structure to Azure. I really thank you for your comments and words but untill now all text do not fit to my question about Azure and the webservices there.

Comment: Yep I get you, but I don't know hot help you further, hopefully some will.